# How to apply method/function to a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**The function is:**

```
def combine(row):
    count = 0
    stage = ""
    if (str(row.doggo) == "doggo"):
        stage = "doggo"
        count += 1

    if row.floofer == "floofer":
        stage = "floofer"
        count += 1

    if row.pupper == "pupper":
        stage = "pupper"
        count += 1

    if row.pupper == "puppo":
        stage = "puppo"
        count += 1

    if count == 0:
        return pd.np.NAN
    elif count == 1:
        return stage
    else:
        return "multiple"
```

**While calling the method:**

```
df_twitter_archive_clean["status"] = df_twitter_archive_clean[["doggo","floofer","pupper","puppo"]].apply(combine)
```

The error message appears:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 df_twitter_archive_clean["status"] = df_twitter_archive_clean[["doggo","floofer","pupper","puppo"]].apply(combine)
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in
>   apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args,
>   **kwds)    6485                          args=args,    6486                          kwds=kwds)
>   -> 6487         return op.get_result()    6488     6489     def applymap(self, func):
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in
>   get_result(self)
>       149             return self.apply_raw()
>       150 
>   --> 151         return self.apply_standard()
>       152 
>       153     def apply_empty_result(self):
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in
>   apply_standard(self)
>       255 
>       256         # compute the result using the series generator
>   --> 257         self.apply_series_generator()
>       258 
>       259         # wrap results
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in
>   apply_series_generator(self)
>       284             try:
>       285                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
>   --> 286                     results[i] = self.f(v)
>       287                     keys.append(v.name)
>       288             except Exception as e:
>
> in combine(row)
>         2     count = 0
>         3     stage = ""
>   ----> 4     if (str(row.doggo) == "doggo"):
>         5         stage = "doggo"
>         6         count += 1
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in
>   **getattr**(self, name)    5065             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):    5066
>   return self[name]
>   -> 5067             return object.**getattribute**(self, name)    5068     5069     def **setattr**(self, name, value):
>
> **AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'doggo'", 'occurred at index doggo')**

Comment: use `axis=1` in `apply()` to indicate columns axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df_twitter_archive_clean["status"] = df_twitter_archive_clean[["doggo","floofer","pupper","puppo"]].apply(combine, axis=1)
```

Otherwise you apply the function column-wise and if I understand you correctly- you want it row-wise

Comment: No worries, please consider upvoting, and mark this post as an answer to close off your question.